# Problem with enabling JavaScript with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, spring-boot, htmlunit

I'm a newbie to HtmlUnit, and I'm writing a demo script to load the source HTML of a webpage and write it to a txt file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (final WebClient wc = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED)) {
        wc.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        
        final HtmlPage page = wc.getPage("https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/gol-ui/SearchResults/biscuits");
        WebResponse res = page.getWebResponse();
        String html = res.getContentAsString();
        
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(dir + "/pageHtml.txt");
        fw.write(html);
        fw.close();
    }
}
```

However, it returns the HTML for disabled JavaScript. To try and fix this, I added this line to *ensure* JS is enabled on the WebClient:

```
        wc.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Despite that, nothing changes. Am I being an idiot, or is there something more subtle that needs to change?

Thanks for any help! ^_^

Comment: What _do_ you get? Are you confirming that you're waiting for asynchronous things to happen? (I suggest considering Geb as a DSL on top of Selenium, as it makes sorting these things out easier.)

Comment: Hi! I do get some HTML back, but it's essentially a plain HTML page telling me that I need to enable JavaScript. I tried to see if this was recreatable with a different page (this time the page for ASDA - it's for a uni project), and this time it tells me my browser is out of date. Kinda stuck here for ideas what to do. The context behind this is for web scraping for an android app, but Jsoup doesn't support JS I believe. I'll try the solution you provided!

Answer (score 1):

```
WebResponse res = page.getWebResponse();
String html = res.getContentAsString();
```

This is the response (code) you got from the server. If you like to have the current DOM (the one after the js processing is done you can do something like

```
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(60_000);

System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

or

```
System.out.println(page.asNormalizedText());
```